# Date format converting in file 'YYYYMMDD' TO 'MM/DD/YYYY'

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have requirement as, In target file date is like `20151125` needs to convert it to `11/25/2015` through informatica. Files are generating from informatica to unix server.

I tried with

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(substr(IN_DATE,16,20),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
FROM DUAL;
```

That would work in oracle but when generating the file in Informatica it's not working.

Comment: what is your source and target? file/database? what is target column datatype?

Comment: Source - Expression transformation(informatica) adding new variable value. v_date = to_char(to_date(substr(FILE_NAME,16,20),'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
Target - File in Unix (it should reflect in Header of file).

Comment: why are you doing substr(FILE_NAME,16,20) if the date is coming as 20151125? The date is part of FILE_NAME? can you show a sample filename?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *,
DATE_FORMAT(`lastUpdated`, '%d.%m.%y') as newdate 
FROM table_name WHERE 1
```

[MySQL DATE_FORMAT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Convert the date column into the date datatype specifying the date format(YYYYMMDD) it should read and then convert it into character representation specifying the format you want(in this case MM/DD/YYYY) in the expression transformation

To_char(to_date(date_column,'YYYYMMDD'),'MM/DD/YYYY')